# How to generate a Dataframe whose length equals to the product of all columns lengths?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, dimension

I am looking for a quick way to generate a long dataframe. For example, the input is:

`Column "color": [1,2,3]`   (length: 3)

`Column "weekday": [0,1]`    (length: 2)

The expected output is:

```
color  weekday
  1        0
  2        0
  3        0
  1        1
  2        1
  3        1
```

And this output dataframe has the length as 2*3 = 6.

Is there a quick way to generate such dataframes based on the series as the input? And it is possible that there are many columns. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand if your input are Serie objects or simple str and list python datatypes

Comment: Sound like you're looking for a [Cartesian product of your inputs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Is that correct?

Comment: @Carmoreno I think it could be Serie objects or several Lists.